# Angular Material design implement filter server side

Tags: angular

How can I implement an [Angular material design](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-data-table/) server-side filter? Im trying to send the filter value to a c# backend, but the SQL seems clunky. For example:

I have results from this query: `select name,email from mydb..mytb` and im trying to filter on the string `jim`. Would my SQL query then become:

`select name,email from mydb..mytb where email like 'jim' or name like 'jim'`

That seems incredibly clunky, to the point where I would be better off using a client side system like [this one](https://codingthesmartway.com/angular-material-part-4-data-table/)

Comment: what if you have 1 billion records. would you then be able to use client side  as well ? if you don't have a lot of records, client side is fine. else. server side is your best option. avoid sql queries and use an ORM, in your case, Entity Framework.

Comment: @Stavm good point.... not thinking of the scale of my data